# Maintaining constant voltage at end of long wire

Tags: wire, voltage

I have a long 1 mm wire, about 1.5 meters long (and 1.5 m back). At the end of a wire I have a device that requires 3.7 V and can pull anywhere from 0 to 6 A at a time. However, when it pulls a high current I am noticing that the voltage drops and the device shuts down. Is there any way I can maintain a constant voltage at the device, regardless of the current drawn?

Some notes:

- Using a thicker wire is not an option.
- I cannot move the power supply closer to the device.

So I am looking for something that can regulate the voltage at the device's end.

Comment: Measure the current and increase the voltage according to U=R*I, where R is your known cable resistance. Commonly called cable drop compensation

Comment: @winny my power supply only allows me to fix the voltage and measure the current. What you're saying requires me to connect an extra wire at the device's end (remote sensing), I assume?

Comment: No, that would be a four wire sensing feedback scheme.If you can't adjust your supply voltage, your only option would be to use a boost converter in the receiving end to increate the voltage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given that you cannot use thicker wire or shorter wire, your options are: -

- Boost the voltage at the sending end by a couple of volts and regulate down to the required voltage at the receiving end (more likely to work)
- Boost and regulate the voltage both at the receiving end (might not work in extremes of load current due to cable resistance)
- Boost somewhere in between and regulate at the receiving end.
- Use a battery at the receiving end to supplement the load current required and let the battery be charged down the cable at a low average current (needs designing with care to ensure it works under all load/time scenarios).

Comment: Thanks Andy, that last point is very useful; I am trying to elongate the device's battery life using an external power supply, and I had not yet thought of keeping the battery connected as well. Couldn't I just connect both the battery and my external power supply to the + and - pins on my device?

Comment: @ThomasW The devil is in the detail and you ought to add an addendum to your question showing precisely what you mean. I'm not going to say it will or won't work without stronger details. Hope you understand.

Comment: @ThomasW Battery charging requires a battery charging circuit or you may damage the battery (which may leak acid or catch fire). If you add this circuit, then yes.

Comment: It may be that charging a LiPo battery to well below its nominal full charge voltage(like 3.8 instead of 4.2V) is reasonably safe, but I would do some further research before concluding that. This site suggests it may be OK : https://www.powerstream.com/lithium-ion-charge-voltage.htm

Comment: Thanks, I just tried it and it worked like a charm! Just requires me to monitor the battery voltage, to make sure it does not get too large.